# How to create a postgres async mock up in python with asyncpg?

Tags: python, postgresql, pytest, fastapi, asyncpg

We have a basic fastapi server with some http and websocket endpoints.
We're using postgres with asyncpg to do some basic CRUD operations.
One example is that there's a post endpoint that creates an item in the DB and notifies the websocket listeners:

```py
async def notify_todo_listeners():
  todos = db_handler.fetch_todos()
  notify_all(todos)

@app.post("/todo")
async def post_todo(request):
  todo = db_handler.insert(request.json())
  asyncio.create_task(notify_todo_listeners())
  return todo
```

And we want to test that endpoint in pytest, so we create a temp postgres DB using docker and we also patch the db_handler to be using a mock connection that we create in the test environment.

That connection is setup so that it would be rolled back once the test is finished

```py
@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="function")
async def session(monkeypatch):
  connection = await asyncpg.connect(CONNECTION_STRING)
  transaction = connection.transaction()
  await transaction.start()

  async def mock_get_connection():
    return connection

  monkeypatch.setattr(database_handler, "get_connection", mock_get_connection)

  yield connection

  transaction.rollback()

async def test_post_todo(session):
  async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as client:
    response = await client.post(some_todo_object)
    
    assert response.status_code == 200
    # some other assertions ...
```

The problem is when we try to test that endpoint, the part where we create a new task for notifying subscribers and using the DB to fetch the todo list raises this error:

```
exception=InterfaceError('cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress')
```

My understanding is that an async connection cannot be used across different co-routines, otherwise we get that error.

Question is, how can we properly mock this database while rolling back all changes made during each test run, while accounting for the possibility of having multiple co-routine tasks running?